# What is the difference between include and required file in php?

Tags: include, require

In php file ofthe we use include and require a file. I think both are used for attaching an external file but when we use include and when require?

Comment: There's no diff. both do the same thing. Require_once will make sure that the script is never included more than once which would ensure you dont get an error saying you tried to redefine things like constants, classes or functions assuming your required file had these in it and you happened to include/require it more than once (without using require_once)

Answer (score 1):

`require()` will cause a fatal error if the file cannot be found, therefore terminating the script.  `include()` will only emit a warning, and the script will continue to run.  So you should use `require()` when you are including a library or something that you *need* for your script, and `include()` when the include is optional.

In practice, I have only ever used `require()`.

Comment: Historically, `require` used to always be called, whether you surrounded it with conditional statements or not. PHP 4.0.2 changed this, so now `require` will behave more sensibly.